# define variable inputs with - parameter for unix

Tags: bash, shell, unix

My question is pretty straight forward but it seems like I can't seem to be able to find an answer with google :(

How do I specify parameters for a function with - parameter for a function I wrote.

For example I wrote this .sh file for bash but it will take 5-6 inputs so it is likely that a user might mess up the order. so how can I make the function run like:

function -m abc@yahoo.com -d dataset.csv -f filter ...

instead of having to write all the parameters in right order for $1, $2, etc.

Thanks

Comment: sounds like getopt/getopts is what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `getopts()`. I think the reason you had trouble was your search terms. You needed stuff like `options`, `switches`, and `arguments` rather than `parameters` and `functions`.

Here is a quick and dirty example.

```
while getopts "h?vf:" opt; do
    case "$opt" in
        h|\?)
            show_help
            exit 0
            ;;
        v)  verbose=1
            ;;
        f)  output_file=$OPTARG
            ;;
    esac
done
```

[source](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/035#getopts)

Comment: #! /usr/bin/bash

optget()
{


while getopts "a:b:" opt; do
   case "$opt" in
       a) out="$OPTARG"
    ;;
       b) out2="$OPTARG"
    ;;
   esac
done
echo "test if we get $out . And this one $out2"

}

this does take in -a but -b automatically becomes OPTARG.So the output of optget -a this -b too ,is: test if we get this . And this one OPTARG

can you help?

Comment: @yatici Hey, I can't really tell why that is not working (it looks like it should), and I don't currently have access to a linux terminal (at work). Maybe try posting it as another question? Only thing is to double check you wrote b) exactly the same way that you wrote a).